# Как осуществить отправку почты через адресную строку браузера?

Tags: php

Как осуществить отправку почты через адресную строку браузера, вот скрипт, к примеру

```
<?php

$to = 'sample@sample.com';
$subject = 'sample';
$message = 'mess1';
$from  = 'sample';

if (isset($_GET['to'])) { $to = $_GET['to']; }  
if (isset($_GET['subject'])) { $subject = $_GET['subject']; } 
if (isset($_GET['message'])) { $message = $_GET['message']; } 
if (isset($_GET['from'])) { $from = $_GET['from']; }

mail ($to, $subject, $mes, $from);

?>
```

Как это будет выглядеть в адресной строке?  Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
http://site.ru/send.php?to=mail@email.ru&subject=Тема&message=Сообщение&from=me@me.ru
```